# how to get value of date picker for ajax

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

following code i am trying to fetch value of datepicker but i am not getting value of datepicker can anyone help me??

```
$('#mm').change(function() {
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/lha/chkholiday";?>',
data:{
date:$('#datepicker').val(),
timeh:$('#hh').val(),
timem:$('#mm').val()
},
type: "POST",
success: function (dataCheck) {
var total = dataCheck;
alert(total);
//document.getElementById("result123").innerHTML = str;
//$('#resultdrop').html(total);
}
});
```

Comment: First (regardless if it should work), your selector for the date is incorrect use `$('#datepicker')` with the `$`

Comment: yeh i did that but still not working

Comment: Yes, it was just a first comment. Could you please add the jQuery piece of code to init the datepicker?? The answer is in!

Answer (score 1):

your code is wrong

```
data:{
     date: $('#datepicker').val(),
     timeh: $('#hh').val(),
     timem: $('#mm').val()
}
```

Also you should change your attributes name

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

```html
<div id="datepicker-container">
<input  type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker"  id="datepicker"/>
</div>
```

In your Javascript:

Here you instruct to load the datepicker when the page loads:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: '-3d'
    });
```

Here you can do something after there has been a "change" on the datepicker, (i.e. the user clicked on a date in the popping calendar):

```js
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {

    //herebelow you assign the chosen date on the datepicker to a variable
    var date = jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

    //or alternatively
    var formattedDate = jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate');
    
    // Do something with the date variable...
    // Such as $.ajax({
    //               url: ...
    //               success:... 
    // })

});
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(date, instance) {

        $.ajax
        ({
              type: "Post",
              url: '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/lha/chkholiday";?>',
              data: date,
              success: function(result)
              {
                  alert(result);
              }
         });  
     }
});
```

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
data:{
    date    : $('#datepicker').val(),
    timeh   : $('#hh').val(),
    timem   : $('#mm').val()
},
```